# How to test smart contract timestamp dependent behavior?

Tags: smart-contract, substrate-contracts-node, testing, timestamp

how can I test block_timestamp-dependent smart contract behavior?
The substrate contact node doesn't allow block_timestamp manipulations.

For context, in the EVM ecosystem, one can use hardhat helpers to setNextBlockTimestamp(timestamp).
https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference